# View Delphi's breakpoints for current file only in Rad Studio XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a large projects with breakpoints in several files. Some disabled, some enabled.

Is there a way to only have listed in the Breakpoint List debug window only those breakpoints belonging to the currently selected file in the code editor?

The list of breakpoints displayed are grouped by units but not alphabetically sorted, so its a bit awkward to navigate when a lot of breakpoints are defined.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to filter the breakpoints by file.  It displays all available breakpoints.  Feel free to submit a feature request to QC.

Comment: I wonder if I could write an IDE plugin to do a smarter breakpoint viewer. :-)